# How to install gettext-devel in redhat/ubi8

Tags: docker, redhat, gettext

I have a docker file where I want to install `gettext-devel`

```
FROM redhat/ubi8
RUN yum install gettext-devel
```

which does not work:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS                                                                                                           3.3 MB/s | 797 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream                                                                                                        7.0 MB/s | 2.6 MB     00:00    
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder                                                                                                120 kB/s |  16 kB     00:00    
No match for argument: gettext-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: gettext-devel
```

How can this package be installed?